# Why is $E[\ \sup_{ 0\leq u \leq t } |X_u|\ ]<\infty$ where $X$ is a right continuous submartingale?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, martingales, stochastic-analysis

Suppose that $ \{ X_t, \mathcal{F}_t \ : \ 0 \leq t < \infty \}$ is a right-continuous submartingale and $T$ is a stopping time of $ \{ \mathcal{F}_t \} $. I have been trying to show unsuccessfully that

$E[\ \sup_{ 0\leq u \leq t } |X_u|\ ] < \infty$.

Is this even true? I get a feeling that s not true but i can't show it either. I was trying to understand the solution of Exercise 3.24 in Chapter 1 of Karatzas and Shreve from

[Problem 3.24 of "Brownian Motion & Stochastic Processes" by Karatzas and Shreve - Submartingales and stopping times](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1500273/problem-3-24-of-brownian-motion-stochastic-processes-by-karatzas-and-shreve).

Comment: Have a look here https://almostsure.wordpress.com/2009/12/20/optional-sampling/ The proof theorem 1 point 2 gives the idea of the proof take $\tau=t$ and $\sigma = t\wedge \tau$. Regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, in general the assertion does not hold true - not even for martingales. You can find several counterexamples [here](https://almostsure.wordpress.com/2016/09/12/martingales-with-non-integrable-maximum/).

What is, however, true is the following statement:

> Let $(M_t)_{t \geq 0}$ be a martingale (or a positive submartingale) with càdlàg sample paths. Then $$\mathbb{E} \left( \sup_{s \leq t} |M_s| \right) \leq \frac{e}{e-1} \mathbb{E}(|M_t| |\log M_t|).$$

You can find a (sketch of the) proof for discrete martingale for instance in Revuz & Yor, Exercise 2.1.16; using standard approximation it can be easily extended to the time-continuous setting.

Comment: So it means that the part of the proof here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1500273/problem-3-24-of-brownian-motion-stochastic-processes-by-karatzas-and-shreve where they prove the integrability of $X_t$ doesnt work?

Comment: @user3503589 Yes, it seems so.