# Is it true that every continuous local martingale is a true martingale

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales, local-martingales

Given a continuous local martingale $X_t$ starting at 0, i.e. $X_0=0$, by the continuity of the paths, we can deduce that $\sup_{0\leq s\leq t}|X_s|<\infty$ P-a.s. Hence, $E[\sup_{0\leq s\leq t}|X_s|]<\infty$, which means, that the following holds:
$$E[X_t\mid F_s]=E[\lim_{n\to \infty}X_{t\wedge T_n}\mid F_s]=\lim_{n\to\infty}E[X_{t\wedge T_n}\mid F_s]=\lim_{n\to\infty}X_{s\wedge T_n}=X_s$$.

The exchange of the limit with the expectation is justified by using dominated convergence theorem. Is this argumentation correct? I have the feeling that the claim is not true, but I cannot find the flaw in my argumentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The flaw in your argumentation is that $\sup_{0 \leq s \leq t} |X_s| < \infty$ does not imply $\mathbb{E}(\sup_{0 \leq s \leq t} |X_s|)< \infty$. This means that the dominated convergence theorem is not applicable. For a given (local) martingale it is, in general, not true that $\mathbb{E}(\sup_{s \leq t} |X_s|) < \infty$, see this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2676406/36150), and therefore this flaw cannot be fixed.

In fact, there are known counterexamples to your assertion; see e.g. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2077827/36150) for such a counterexample.